# Plotting means of variable using barchart

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataset:

```
x    y     z
1    4     7
9    3     2
```

How would I be able to plot all 3 variables mean in a single graph using seaborn barplot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use seaborn you need to have a column for mean values and a column to specify from which variable the mean comes from.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [1,9], 'y' : [4,3], 'z' : [7,2]})
new_df = pd.DataFrame({"columns" : df.columns, "mean" : df.mean()})
sns.barplot(x="columns", y="mean", data=new_df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: That's not necessarily the case. If you compute the means in a vector `y`, you can use x as a vector of indices like `range(len(means))` and simply call `sns.barplot(x=x, y=y)` with no DataFrames involved.

Comment: You're right! The problem I see is that you are losing automatic labelling and legending that make the use of seaborn with pandas so handy.

Comment: Yes, I agree that using DataFrames is how seaborn is best used, I just wanted to make sure that OP does not think that you necessarily need one in order to use seaborn.